# After duplicating a target in xcode 6 and building with iOS8 sdk unable to install / open it

Tags: build, duplicates, ios8, xcode6, target

All I get when trying to build that target is :
"The file “appname.app” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Actually fixed using ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} as executable file value in the new copied info.plist.