# How can I access the contents of a folder selected from Files app?

Tags: ios

Basically my app works like a iCloud-based note app (for example, logseq). Users first select a folder in Files app, then my app starts downloading/updating the contents of the folder.

So I implemented folder selection via `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, after I got the folder path in Files app. I tried downloading a hardcoded file like (`<the folder path user just selected>/fileList.json`) via `FileManager.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem`, got 257 permission error (the file does exist in my icloud drive). Then I followed the answer from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223929/how-do-i-get-around-nscocoaerrordomain257-when-pulling-a-file-from-the-files-ap) to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource`. It always returns false and the same 257 error returned.

Perhaps, I cannot access a random file from a selected folder? but how can those note apps work by simply letting users selecting a root folder?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after some debugging. Call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` on the folder path you grabbed from picker, not its subfiles. After that, you can start downloading its subfiles via `startDownloadingUbiquitousItem`